# sed no output on no pattern match

Tags: linux, sed

I want `sed` to give me a single line output irrespective of whether the matched pattern is found and substituted, or even if there is no pattern match, with same command options.

```
1. echo "700K" | sed -n 's/[A-Z]//gp'    // gives one output

2. echo "700" | sed -n 's/[A-Z]//gp'    // no output
```

Is there any way in sed i can get a single output for second case without removing the "-n" option, forcing it to print the input irrespective of substitution made or not?

Comment: Please Format you commands and text, so that it's easier to read, for more information read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear for me why you need to keep the `-n` option but if you really do need to keep it you can use the following `sed` command:

```
echo "700" | sed -n 's/[A-Z]//g;p'
```

this will first make the substitution if possible then print the line.

**output:**

[image]

Comment: without the -n option the first case is giving me 2 outputs,which i do not want.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to mess with all these sed options. Use sed in it's simpliest format which will make a substitution if pattern is found:

```
$ echo "700K" | sed 's/[A-Z]//g'
700
$ echo "700" | sed 's/[A-Z]//g'
700

$ sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.4

$ sed 's/[A-Z]//g' <<<$'700\n700K\n500\n3500A'
700
700
500
3500
```